# Python multiplication function not working

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner to python wanted to make a simple calculator app which takes multiple inputs for the case of operators 'Add' and 'Multiply'. I was having a problem with the operator 'Multiply where wrong outputs are being diplayed. So can any one help me with the syntax. I would also be thankful if you help me improve the other parts of the code.

```
print("Type Add to add the numbers")
print("Type Subtract to subtract the numbers")
print("Type Multiply to multiply the numbers")
print("Type Divide to divide the numbers")

Operator = input()

if Operator == "Add":
    print("Type the number of numbers you want to add" )
    Num_Numbers = range(0,int(input()))
    Total = 0
    for Count in Num_Numbers:
        print("Type Num"+str(Count+1))
        Count = int(input())
        Total = Total + Count
    print(Total)


elif Operator == "Subtract":
    print("Type the first number")
    Num1 = float(input())
    print("Type the second number")
    Num2 = float(input())
    print(Num1 - Num2)

elif Operator == "Multiply":
    print("Type the number of numbers you want to multiply" )
    Num_Numbers = range(0,int(input()))
    Total = 0
    Counter = 0
    for Count in Num_Numbers:
        print("Type Num"+str(Count+1))
        count = int(input())
        if Counter != 0:
            Counter = Counter + 1
            while Total == 0:
                Total = Total + count
                print("Code implemented")
        else:
            continue
        Total = Total * count
    print(Total)

elif Operator == "Divide":
    try:
     print("Type the first number")
     Num1 = float(input())
     print("Type the second number")
     Num2 = float(input())
     print(Num1 / Num2)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
     print("Division by zero not possible")

else:
    print("Operator Unidentified!")
```

Comment: What's the problem? Please be as specific as possible about what you'd like to get an answer to or solution for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elif Operator == "Multiply":
    print("Type the number of numbers you want to multiply" )
    Num_Numbers = range(0,int(input()))
    Total = 1.0
    for Count in Num_Numbers:
        print("Type Num"+str(Count+1))
        count = float(input())     #chances are the number can be float
        Total = Total * count
    print(Total)
```

Just simplified your code!

Answer (score 0):

You put the start `Total` as 0. 0 multiplied by anything is 0, so you should start at 1:

```
Total = 1
```

It's more math than programming.

You also need to remove the strange lines (what are they for?!) shown below:

```
Counter = 0
#some needed lines
    if Counter != 0:
        Counter = Counter + 1
        while Total == 0:
            Total = Total + count
            print("Code implemented")
    else:
        continue
```

Note for the future that:

```
var=var+1
```

Is quicker written as:

```
var+=1
```

And the same for other operators, and:

```
else:
    continue
```

Is obsolete, you don't *need* a `else` statement for every `if`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. They really helped.